# Sql Convert Date using exact format

Tags: c#, sql-server

In SQL 2014, following query works fine.

```
select Convert(datetime, 'JAN 13 2014 1:14:00:000PM', 109)
select Convert(datetime, '13 JAN 2014 1:14:00:000PM', 109)
```

As per [documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa226054(v=SQL.80).aspx), 109 represents foramt 'mon dd yyyy hh:mi:ss:mmmAM (or PM)' as input/output.

How can I ensure that SQL must fail if expected format is not provided. In above example, 2nd query must fail. I don't want to go CLR or any other custom function.

Comment: Do you have to convert it into SQL, is it an option to convert it in your c# application?

Comment: Unfortunately C# way will require lots of changes, and should be last option. CLR will downgrade the performance as too many data to be converted.

Comment: What data type are you using in application and in database?

Comment: Application creates dynamic query and place the query inside dynamically created DTSX. DTSX finally executes the query. This is just an example, expecting SQL server to behave like TryParseExact works in C#. As of now, expected datatype will be date, datetime, datetimeoffset in DB, and app is creating SQL so it will be always a string.

Answer (score 2):

The style parameter ( the 109 ) in the convert function is only used when converting from a datetime to string, as stipulated in the link you supplied. 
When converting to datetime, the style parameter (109) has no effect...

This query will also work in SQL, because the style parameter is ignored when converting to a datetime.

```
select Convert(datetime, 'JAN 13 2014 1:14:00:000PM', 234234)
select Convert(datetime, '13 JAN 2014 1:14:00:000PM', 234234)
```

If you need the string '13 JAN 2014 1:14:00:000PM' to fail, you'll have to do a manual check. something like....

```
DECLARE @DateToCheck    VARCHAR(30) = '13 JAN 2014 1:14:00:000PM'
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN ISNUMERIC(LEFT(@DateToCheck, 2)) = 1 THEN 0
        ELSE ISDATE(@DateToCheck)
    END
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the reverse conversion is the same value:

```sql
SELECT (select Convert(datetime, 'JAN 13 2014  1:14:00:000PM') as mydate) 
WHERE Convert(nvarchar, Convert(datetime, 'JAN 13 2014  1:14:00:000PM'), 109) 
        = 'JAN 13 2014  1:14:00:000PM'
```

(Watch the double spaces)

In a query against a table this will look less contrived than this single-row table.